# Why is my code not incrementing the count?

Tags: python, increment

I have a function (from a part of my code) which is supposed to increment the count whenever I run the function, however, the count only stays at 1. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
def add_a_team():
    csv_team_count = 0
    team_adder = []
    csv_team_count += 1
    print(csv_team_count)

    if csv_team_count <4:
        for i in range(0,6):
            name = str(input("You are now entering the data for Team 1.\nYou will see this 6 times, enter the team's name first then the members, all individually."))
            team_adder.append(name)

    else:
        print("Team count of 4 has been filled in! You cannot add another team!")

    print("\n")

    with open('teams.csv', 'a', newline = '', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        #writing the data for each team.
        writer.writerow(team_adder)

    f.close()
```

Comment: Where do you expect it to grow more than once given you only increase it once?

Comment: @Sayse My bad! I see what I did wrong now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you initialize the function the value is set to 0.

```
 csv_team_count = 0
```

After you increment to 1, but if you call again the function it will set to 0. This value needs to be set outside the function and be passed as arg.

Comment: why does it? it only appears to be used inside of the function

Comment: Exactly. Think about it, everytime you call the function, the first thing it says is 'SET COUNT TO 0'. So even if you increment after that, when you call it again it will say the same thing and the value will be set to 0. That is why is has to be said outside the function, so when you call the function it does not set the value to 0, just increment it

Comment: How can I can call a global variable inside of the function?

Comment: Be careful with modifying the value of global variables inside a function. In any case, you need to declare outside the function and pass the value as argument.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arguments.asp